# ( Scrapy) NotImplementedError: ScraperrSpider.parse callback is not defined

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy. I was seeing a tutorial and implementing a spider but this error always keeps up coming. Please help. I have tried everywhere but I can't fix it.
[This is the error I think](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teKGY.png)

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuzsT.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the indent of the `parse` method. It should be a member of the class not a stand-alone function.